# How to tell which product did user bought in server for IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to do receipt validation on server, which is quite normal for security concern.  But I my case, there is a database on my server recording which products user purchased and provide services according to those records on server. So, I tried to read data from receipt from apple server response to find out what,when,how much user bought the items. But according to apple docs It seems that apple reserved the right to change the json keys for each data field.

So, what's the right way to inform server about receipt information on server side securely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen the bit about fields changing in any docs.  In the response to the server validation request there is a receipt object.  Each object has fields including "product_id", "quantity", "purchase_date" and several other pieces of information.   These fields contain the information you want.   My server validation code makes active use of the product_id so I am confident it works.  Haven't used the others.

My response is based on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html and my server side code.